# Binding key values of a dictionnary in a ListView C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-8

I have a problem in binding elements of my dictionnary.My dictionnary contains an object as a key and an integer as a value.I have to bind this dictionnary in a ListView.The problem is that I need to reach properties of my object to bind them in the listview.Properties type is string.I didn't find solution, it's all about wpf but I'm using Windows8 with MVVM Light.

There is my code:

My List :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MotDansTweet}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="570"
          Margin="64,28,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="350"
          Background="#FF009BB4"
          Grid.Column="1">
  <StackPanel Height="118"
              Width="340">
    <Grid Height="100">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="122"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="330"
            Margin="0,0,0,-22">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="137*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="193*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Key.ProfileImageUrl }"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Height="112"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="127" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key.Username}"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="10,10,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="46"
                   Width="173" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Values}"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="10,61,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Height="41"
                   Width="154" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</ListView>
```

My Dictionnary :

```
 private Dictionary<ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal,int> _motDansTweet ;
    public Dictionary<ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal, int> MotDansTweet
    {
        get { return _motDansTweet; }
        set
        {
            _motDansTweet = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MotDansTweet");
        }
    }
```

My Object :

```
    public class ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal
{
    public string Username { get; set; } // I need it
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; } //I need it
    public int StatusesCount { get; set; }
    public int FollowerCount { get; set; }
    public int FriendsCount { get; set; }
    public int ListedCount { get; set; }
    public List<User> ListeFollower = new List<User>(); 

    public ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal()
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error or what?

Answer (score 1):

I coded something on Win7 WPF, but that should work for you, too:

C#:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            _motDansTweet = new Dictionary<ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal, int>();
            _motDansTweet.Add(new ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal { Username = "Karl1" }, 1);
            _motDansTweet.Add(new ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal { Username = "Karl2" }, 2);
            _motDansTweet.Add(new ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal { Username = "Karl3" }, 3);
            _motDansTweet.Add(new ObjetFollowingFollowerFinal { Username = "Karl4" }, 4);

            Resources["MotDansTweet"] = MotDansTweet;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MotDansTweet}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Key"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key.Username}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the ItemTemplate instead of directly put the StackPanel in the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MotDansTweet}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="570" Margin="64,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Background="#FF009BB4" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Height="118" Width="340">
                <Grid Height="100">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="122" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" Margin="0,0,0,-22">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="137*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="193*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Key.ProfileImageUrl }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="112" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key.Username}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="46" Width="173"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Values}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="41" Width="154"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```